# TCP reset due to java.io.EOFException?

Tags: java, apache, exception, servlets, eof

Our users are seeing TCP resets which they believe is originating from our server or an intermediate device in between.

On our server application log, I can see the error which tallies with the time(s) they are seeing the resets.

The stack trace is below:

```
May 14, 2016 5:04:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet adity threw exception
java.io.EOFException
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readUByte(GZIPInputStream.java:207)
        at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readUShort(GZIPInputStream.java:197)
        at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readHeader(GZIPInputStream.java:136)
        at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:58)
        at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:68)
        at com.osmoticweb.gzipfilter.GZIP2WayRequestStream.<init>(GZIP2WayRequestStream.java:20)
        at com.osmoticweb.gzipfilter.GZIP2WayRequestWrapper.<init>(GZIP2WayRequestWrapper.java:25)
        at com.osmoticweb.gzipfilter.GZIP2WayFilter.doFilter(GZIP2WayFilter.java:40)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:555)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

My question is: Is it our application that is causing the resets or is it the client?

Apologies for the lack of technicality around this question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the client.

There are two possibilities:

1) Client is not sending all data.
2) Client putting a wrong value content-lenght header.

Comment: Just to clarify, by client you mean the client's system sending the request right? and not our application